# Apagar determinado valor de um campo do banco de dados separado por vírgulas e reinserir novamente

Tags: php

Preciso apagar um valor de um campo do banco de dados separado por vírgulas e reinserir novamente.

Com a função *str_replace* do PHP consigo apagar todos menos o primeiro ou último, pois sempre sobra uma vírgula. Estou testando a função *end* do PHP, mais agradeço qualquer solução.

```
$referenciaDel; // 44 

$referencia; // 44,45,46

$replace = str_replace(",".$referenciaDel,"",$referencia);
```

Se for o primeiro valor a ser apagado não funciona pois adicionei a vírgula na função, e o primeiro valor não tem vírgula antes.

Comment: Esse número vem de um link? vem apenas um número ou vem assim `43,45` ?

Comment: Vem um único string do campo do banco de dados (tudo junto)  @rray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode converter a sua string em um array e remover o valor específico.

```
//Converte a string em um array. Nesse caso o delimitador é a vírgula
$array = explode(",", $referencia); //[44,45,46]

//Adiciona em um array todos os números que serão removidos
$paraRemover = array($referenciaDel); //[44]

//Retorna apenas os itens que não são comuns entre os arrays
$resultado = array_diff($array, $paraRemover); //[45,46]
```

Para voltar a gerar uma string do resultado separado por vírgula:

```
$string = implode(",", $resultado); //45,46
```

Comment: Perfeito @Filipe Moraes, obrigado.